# Javascript DOM - aligning a text element to the center?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, position

I have a text node attached to a div that I want to position in the middle of the page. These elements are attached to a mainDiv which is like the whole page. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
title = document.createElement('div');
title.appendChild(document.createTextNode("The big title!"));
title.style.color = "#F5AE20";
title.style.textAlign = "center"; //this is what I'm trying to solve my problem

mainDiv.appendChild(title);
```

Unfortunately the title stays on the top left of the page; I want it top centered. 
EDIT - just to clarify, I would like to do this within Javascript if possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/eN3Mc/ You code appears to work, so my guess is it has something to do with a parent element's width/positioning/float/etc...

Comment: Agree with @Jared.  Your code is working fine for me.  If parent is floated or position absolute that would certainly explain it as the parent will wrap to the size of the widest child element.

Comment: the parent is literally just (in html) <div id="mainDiv"></div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just from what you've posted, we can't give you a definitive answer.

We need to take into consideration what's defined in your CSS and also the parents of the DIV you're inserting.

Setting the left and right margins to auto, for instance, won't work for a div that doesn't have a defined width, and setting text-align to be center won't work as expected for a div whose width has been constrained.

Here's some example code that definitely works, anyway:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayResult()
{
title = document.createElement('div');
title.appendChild(document.createTextNode("The big title!"));
title.style.color = "#F5AE20";
title.style.textAlign = "center"; //this is what I'm trying to solve my problem

document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(title); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1">This is some text.</div>
<br />

<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Align text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the mainDiv hasn't been constrained and there's currently no css code.

Answer (score 1):

try setting the left and right margins to 'auto'

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a comment... ;)