# Javascript function, trying to create a link and set its alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright, so to start with let's look at this:

```jscript
function displayResult() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    a.title = "my title text";
    a.style.cssText = "text-align:center;"
    a.href = "http://example.com";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

This is run from a button click, but when it creates the new link it isn't aligned to the center. I'm not sure why, and I was hoping to get some help.

Comment: Use `a.style.textAlign`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript DOM - aligning a text element to the center?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071831/javascript-dom-aligning-a-text-element-to-the-center)

Comment: `a.style.cssText = "text-align:center; display: block;"` would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the centered text effect, you need to make your link tag a block element, as the `text-align` property will only apply to block level elements (`a` tags are per default inline). You can either use camel cased CSS attributes, e.g. Javascript: `textAlign` for CSS: [`text-align`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align):

```
a.style.display = "block";
a.style.textAlign = "center";
```

Here is a working example:

```js
function displayResult() {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.title = "my title text";
  a.style.textAlign = "center";
  a.style.display = "block";
  a.href = "http://example.com";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayResult()">Click</button>
```

Or you can also use the [cssText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText) property (thanks for mentioning in the comments):

```
a.style.cssText = "text-align:center; display: block;";
```

```js
function displayResult() {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.title = "my title text";
  a.style.cssText = "display:block; text-align:center;";
  a.href = "http://example.com";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="displayResult()">Click</button>
```

Comment: In your CSS section. But for the case of using ONLY Javascript, I've updated the question.

Comment: `a.style.cssText = "text-align:center; display: block;"` works as well. So saying `cssText` isn't useful is not really correct.